# Bash. Recursive directory creation permission check

Tags: bash, mkdir, dirname

I want in Bash to create recursively a dir checking first if the user has permissions. I know that `mkdir -p` will create all the subdirs but the point is that I want to check if the user is able to do it before doing it.

In my program, a path is given by the user to create the dir. Let's suppose the var `givenpath` with value `/root/newdir/anothernewone`. User root is going to be able to create it but any other normal user is not going to be able to create it. I want to check if the user is able to do it. My non-working approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

givenpath="/root/newdir/" # This works
#givenpath="/root/newdir/anothernewone/" # This is not working

if [ -d $(dirname "${givenpath}") ]; then
    if [ ! -w $(dirname "${givenpath}") ]; then
        echo "Error, You don't have write permissions"
    else
        echo "Yeah, there are permissions"
    fi
else
    echo "Error, base dir to create subdirs is not existing"
fi
```

This is not working completely. With `givenpath` `/root/newdir` it will work because basedir is `/root/` and it's correctly checked for both users, but if more subdirs are given like `/root/newdir/anothernewone` it will fail because basedir is `/root/newdir/` so the basedir is not existing yet and it will fail for both users.

The point is to be able to create the dirs checking first if is possible. Maybe one solution could be do a recursive check of every dir starting on the given first level until reach a non-existing dir checking if there are write permission on the last existing...

Another very very dirty approach I'm thinking in, could be to launch the `mkdir -p` command and check the exit code. If it's different than 0, everything clear, no permissions... and if it's 0 ok, there are permissions but then I should delete the created directories because what I want is to check without creating the dirs.

but I don't know how to do it. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: If you have write access to directory /root, when is it not possible to create all subdirectories?

Comment: Good point... but, if the givenpath is `/newdir/anothernewone` , how to differentiate the base dir to check? how can I know that I must check / instead of /newdir ??

Comment: I don't see a problem here. If you try `mkdir -p /some/long/path/to/my/dir`, then you'll either succeed in creating any intermediate directories, or the first non-existing directory you attempt to create will fail, leaving you with an unmodified file system. You're never doing to be able to, for example, start with `/some/long`, then successfully create `/some/long/path`, then fail to create `/some/long/path/to` (at least, due to permissions).

Comment: Yeah but what I need is to know that the mkdir is able to write, not to write. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a recursive function... still on testing but maybe it could be a solution. Please, if somebody can contribute to improve it, it is welcome:

```
#!/bin/bash

#givenpath="/root/" #root can write, user not
givenpath="/root/newdir/anothernewone/" #root can write, user not
#givenpath="/home/user/newdir" #both user and root can write

function dir_permission_check() {

    if [ -w "${1}" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        basedir=$(dirname "${1}")
        if [ "${basedir}" != "/" ]; then
            if dir_permission_check "${basedir}"; then
                return 0
            else
                return 1
            fi
        elif [ -w "${basedir}" ]; then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
        fi
   fi
}

dir_permission_check "${givenpath}"
echo $?
```

If an exit code of 0 is returned, there is permissions to write, otherwise the user has not permissions. Any opinion about this function I did? maybe it is not too much elegant solution but it seems it's working.

**EDIT**

It seems the function is working ok. Here is one improved and more clean:

```
#!/bin/bash

#givenpath="/root/" #root can write, user not
givenpath="/root/newdir/anothernewone/" #root can write, user not
#givenpath="/home/user/newdir" #both user and root can write

function dir_permission_check() {

    if [ -e "${1}" ]; then
        if [ -d "${1}" ] && [ -w "${1}" ] && [ -x "${1}" ]; then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
        fi
    else
        dir_permission_check "$(dirname "${1}")"
        return $?
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrought example of how you could check by actually trying to create a test folder :

```
function check_dir_permissions() {
    givenpath="${1}"
    if [ ! -d $(dirname "${givenpath}") ]; then
        echo "failed: directory doesn't exist"
        return 0
    fi

    tmp_dir="test_dir_check_folder-${RANDOM}"
    curr_pwd=$(pwd)

    cd "${givenpath}"
    mkdir  "${givenpath}/${tmp_dir}"  2>/dev/null
    test=$?
    [[ -d "${givenpath}/${tmp_dir}" ]] && rmdir "${givenpath}/${tmp_dir}"
    cd "$curr_pwd"

    if [ $test -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Failed: on Permissions"
        return 1 
    else
        echo "Success: You have permissions"
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Sample:

```
$ ./check_dir.sh /root
failed
You DO NOT have the permissions to write to [/root] 

$ ./check_dir.sh /tmp
good
You have the permissions to write to [/tmp]
```

You could wrap the function in a loop that goes through each folder and checks  and stops if it finds a problem, I have to admit this is a weird approach but you may have a specific use case .